# Make SwiftUI view to expand to UIHostingController size

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that needs to be shown in a UIKit View Controller. I'm using `UIHostingController` to embed my SwiftUI view.

I'm trying to figure out how can my SwifUI view expands its size to match UIHostingController's frame. My `UIHostingController` currently has the same frame as `backgroundImageView` of the the `ViewController` but my `FeatureIntroductionView` does not expand to fit in `UIHostingController`

[image]

**This is my SwiftUI view**

```
struct FeatureIntroductionView: View {

let image: String
let title: String
let subtitle: String
let buttonTitle: String

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 33) {
        Image(image)
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font(UIFont.boldFontWith(size: 28)))
                
            Text(subtitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font(UIFont.regularFontWith(size: 16)))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

        }
        
        SecondaryButton(title: buttonTitle) {
            // Close
        }
    }
    .padding(48)
    .background(.ultraThinMaterial,
                in: Rectangle())
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

}
```

}

**I'm embedding it like below in my UIViewController**

```
func addIntroductoryView() {
    let swipeFeatureIntroductionView = FeatureIntroductionView(image: "Swipe",
                                                               title: "Swipe to change",
                                                               subtitle: "Switch between quotes by swiping gesture or tapping on the screen.",
                                                               buttonTitle: "Got it")

    var swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swipeFeatureIntroductionView)
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    addChild(swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController)
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view.frame = backgroundImageView.frame
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view?.clipsToBounds = true
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.view)
    swipeFeatureIntroductionHostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

I'm looking for a way to expand `FeatureIntroductionView` to fill the same space as backgrodun image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re applying your `.frame` after you apply your `.background`.

This means that the background view is applied to the area of the view as determined by its contents, and when the view’s frame is expanded the background stays the same size.

Try switching the order of the modifiers so that the frame size is readjusted before the background is applied.

```swift
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: Rectangle())
```

Comment: You're exactly right! Thanks